# Derivation of integral with parameters

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Can I get any help with the following problem:

Having $ f(x\sqrt{t} , t) $ and $f$ is infinitely derivable and $g=
 g(t) = \int_\infty^\infty f(x\sqrt{t} , t)N'(x)dx $ and $ N'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$

1) Determine $\frac{dg}{dt}$

2)Consider having $f(x,t)$ that verifies $\frac{1}{2}\frac{df^2}{dx^2}+\frac{df}{dt}=0$

Do an integration on the result of 1) to get $\frac{dg(t)}{dt}=0$

3) What is the value of $g(t)$ for any $t$ knowing that $N'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}=1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please add your work, what you tried, so we can help you in the best way possible.

Comment: I tried integrating by parts the g(t) integral but i did know where to go from there or if that is the correct way to go.
And i know that N(x) is the Gaussien integral but also dont know how to use that

Comment: dg/dt should be something like ∫∞∞df(xt√,t)/dt N′(x)dx